# Seaborn FacetGrid: while mapping a stripplot dodge not implemented

Tags: keyword, seaborn, facet-grid

Using Seaborn, I'm trying to generate a factorplot with each subplot showing a stripplot. In the stripplot, I'd like to control a few aspects of the markers.

Here is the first method I tried:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time",  hue="smoker")
g = g.map(sns.stripplot, 'day', "tip", edgecolor="black", 
          linewideth=1, dodge=True, jitter=True, size=10)
```

And produced the following output without dodge

[image: output no dodge]

While most of the keywords were implemented, the hue wasn't dodged.

I was successful with another approach:

```
kws = dict(s=10, linewidth=1, edgecolor="black")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.factorplot(x='day', y='tip', hue='smoker', col='time', data=tips,
          kind='strip',jitter=True, dodge=True, **kws, legend=False)
```

This gives the correct output:
[image: correct output]

In this output, the hue is dodged.

My question is: why did `g.map(sns.stripplot...)` not dodge the hue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hue` parameter would need to be mapped to the `sns.stripplot` function via the `g.map`, instead of being set as `hue` to the `Facetgrid`.

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time")
g = g.map(sns.stripplot, 'day', "tip", "smoker", edgecolor="black", 
          linewidth=1, dodge=True, jitter=True, size=10)
```

[image]

This is because `map` calls `sns.stripplot` individually for each value in the `time` column, and, if `hue` is specified for the complete `Facetgrid`, for each hue value, such that `dodge` would loose its meaning on each individual call.

I can agree that this behaviour is not very intuitive unless you look at the [source code of `map`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/5ba1e2c7e3b32919a3c9ce1b411f2025ff8fc09e/seaborn/axisgrid.py#L671) itself.

Note that the above solution causes a Warning:

```
lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py:1166: FutureWarning:elementwise comparison failed;
   returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  hue_mask = self.plot_hues[i] == hue_level
```

I honestly don't know what this is telling us; but it seems not to corrupt the solution for now.

Comment: This really made my day! I was passing the color variable as hue in the FacetGrid, while I could have simply passed it in the map function